# Error uploading new app version with Mac Catalyst

Tags: xcode, mac-catalyst

The message that I receive when I try to upload a new app version (1.1) for Mac Catalyst.

ERROR ITMS-90061: "This bundle is invalid. The value for key CFBundleVersion [ 1 ] in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously uploaded version [2]. Please find more information about CFBundleVersion at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleversion"

I have iOS app, which is version 2.6 and the Mac OS app is version 1.0

I changed in Info.plist CFBundleVersion to 1.1 , but I still receive that error.

[image: screenshot of the error]

Comment: This is not a proper solution!

Comment: The weird thing is that the behaviour is different for Mac apps compared with iOS apps.

Comment: were you able to fix this? I am currently having the same issue right now

Comment: I'm currently trying to upload v0.2 over v0.1 and I;m having the exact same issue. I even resorted to trying the comment by @matt and it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

1. Try changing the build number to the latest build number + 1 from version 1.1
2. Such an error may occur if your application has been checked and is awaiting release.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same problem

> solution is to **increase the build number**.

Changing the version number fails to upload the App
[image]